# What's the best way to load balance between Cloud Run services across projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, load-balancing, google-cloud-run

Consider a scenario with two identical Cloud Run services ("Real Time App") deployed in two different regions, let's say EU and US. These services use Firestore for real time communication, and minimizing latency is important. Since Firestore only allows specifying one region per project, each Cloud Run service is deployed in its own project and uses its regional Firestore instance. It is not needed for a service in the US to access Firestore data in the EU and vice versa.

**Is there a way to deploy a global HTTPS load balancer to route requests to Cloud Run service closest to the user when services are defined in different projects?**

I attempted a setup with a shared VPC between a Host "Global" project (in the US) and 2 service projects (EU and US). I created a Cloud Run Service, Network Endpoint Group (NEG), and Backend Service in each regional project. I then attempted to create a Global forwarding rule, Target HTTPs proxy, and URL Map in the host project. However, the URL Map cannot be fed a backend service in another project, complaining that:

> Cross-project references for this resource are not allowed.

Indeed, per the [Shared VPC Architecture](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#shared-vpc) and [Cross-project service referencing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#cross-project) section of the documentation it seems that:

> Cross-project service referencing is not supported for the global external HTTP(S) load balancer

and that, if I understood correctly, the following rules apply:

- The NEG must be defined in the same project as the Cloud Run Service
- The Backend Service must be in the same project as the NEG
- The Target HTTP(s) Proxy and associating URL map must be in the same project as the Backend Service
- The Forwarding Rule must be in the same project as the Backend Service

essentially requiring the entire chain to be defined in one project.

Are there recommended workarounds for this scenario?

One solution I can think of is to create a "Router" Cloud Run Service in the Host global project behind a load balancer, with multi region deployment. Its sole purpose is to respond to the client with the regional URL endpoint of the closest "Real Time App" Cloud Run service.

I am wondering whether there is a more elegant solution, though.

Comment: I have 2 solutions in mind: Either use a router in your HTTPS load balancer project that is deployed in each region (but you add an additional latency, and it's bad for your use case). Or use a third party network layer, like CloudFlare (I don't know their service, but I'm sure they will have a solution for you)

Comment: Tanks Guillaume. When you say "router" do you mean a custom Cloud Run Service / Cloud Function? If so, that's what I had in mind. I think the latency penalty can be paid just once if the client has logic that remembers the result.

Comment: Yes, I had in mind a custom Cloud RUn, with a NGINX for instance to play the role of reverse proxy. But you can also imagine answering a redirect (301) and like that inform the client that in the US they have to use that URL (same for EU).

Comment: Thank you, Guillaume. This sounds like a viable option.

Comment: Let me know which one works the best. It's always great to have real world feedback!!

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I'll try CloudFlare, as I'm trying to stick fully with GCP. But I'll build a router and post a comment with cross-continent latency stats once I have it set up. Thanks again!

Comment: I would not use Cloud Run as a router. The latencies introduced will negate what you are trying to achieve with geolocation-based routing. Instead, I would bite the bullet and put each Cloud Run service in the same project and let Google's global load balancers do their job. Then you can also benefit from Cloud Storage, CDN, and Cloud Armor if required.

Comment: Thanks John. The issue is that only one Firestore instance is allowed per project, and Firestore is region-bound. If the project is setup with Firestore in the US, every EU user will pay a latency penalty for each request - a big minus for Real Time. What I like about the alternate Cloud Run "router" approach with several projects, is that such users pay the latency penalty only once (assuming the client side remembers the US / EU endpoint it needs to communicate with moving forward after the initial request).

Comment: **Assuming the client side remembers ..* What is the client? Custom code or a web browser? Browsers will remember permanent redirects. For custom code, you might as well embed the geolocation in the client. Large-scale systems like MongoDB solve this using DNS + SRV records. The client determines the closest endpoint from a list and goes there.

Comment: Interesting, I wan't familiar with SRV. The client in this case is a browser, so I was thinking of storing the endpoint in a local storage or cookies for the Real Time part. CDN on the host project delivers the documents and assets, and the JS then inquires the global router service for which regional endpoint to use (service project). This gets stored in local storage for further use by the client-side app with some reasonable expiration scheme. No HTTP redirects take place in this scenario, just plain JS fetch to different endpoints which are determined programmatically.

Comment: @AmitA If you got the solution, please post it. So, that it will be helpful for the other community members.